# React rerender component on database change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

Im trying to develop a dynamic todoList.

I have two components TodoList, and Todo. TodoList fetches with useSWR the data from Mongo and puts the data in a div depending if they're completed or not.

Todo component has a button to mark if the task its completed or not. When you click the input check it changes automatically on mongo.

Now I want that these change is reflected in the list too. For example, if a task its not completed it appears in todos.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Np3.png)

When I check the input in DB its marked as completed, but It still appears as not completed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEsy4.png)

TodoList.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import axios from 'axios';
import Todo from './Todo';

const fetcher = (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)

export default function TodoList() {

  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/v1/todos-all', fetcher)
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>To Do</h1>
        {
          data.todos.map((todo: any) => !todo.completed ? (<Todo key={todo._id} id={todo._id} title={todo.title} completed={todo.completed}/>) : (<></>))
        }
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>Completed</h1>
        {
          data.todos.map((todo: any) => todo.completed ? (<Todo key={todo._id} id={todo._id} title={todo.title} completed={todo.completed}/>) : (<></>))
        }
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Todo.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import axios from 'axios';

interface ITodo {
    title: string;
    id: string;
    completed: boolean;
}

const TodoSyle = styled.div`
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    `;

export default function Todo({title, id, completed}: ITodo) {

    const [checked, setChecked]= useState(completed)

    const handleClick = () => {

        setChecked(!checked)

        axios.put(`/api/v1/todo/${id}`, {"completed": `${!completed}`})
    }

    console.log(id)

    return (
        <TodoSyle>
            {title}
            <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={handleClick}/>
        </TodoSyle>
    )
}
```

Until you refresh the pag., which fetches the data again from db and it works. Is there a way to make rerender the app when the check button is clicked? Or there is a beeter approach to these problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useSWR` won't automatically refetch (revalidate) data by default, the cache will still be having the old data.

You can either enable automatic refetch using the `refreshInterval` option.

```
const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/v1/todos-all', fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 });
```

Or explicitly update the data in cache yourself using a mutation after the PUT request to the API.

```
axios.put(`/api/v1/todo/${id}`, {"completed": `${!completed}`})
  .then(() => {
      mutate()
  })
```

Comment: Hmm, that's nice. But thi will affec a lot in perfomance. Would be better if theres a ways that when you click the button, makes a call to useSWR in todoList again? I dont know if that'd be possible but It should have better perfomance

Comment: I dont think that is possible, what you can do is, instead of using a general ```mutate()``` you can use ```mutate('/api/v1/todos-all')``` which will target this specific cache and will not cause any performance issues

Comment: OK thanks, that works, anoher solution I've came up with is use a state in TodoList independent of the DB, and that state controlls if it should be in completed or todo. Will ot have best perfomance. E.g: `const [completed, setCompleted] = useState([data])` Here data is the initial fetch

Comment: Yes using a local state you can render the data quickly to the user (real-time like experience), because in your implementation you are making a put request and then revalidating the cache which will take some compared to local state changes, however as the list grows frequent state changes will also affect performance.

Comment: I'm asking because with this approach it has a delay about 0.5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `useSWR` hook before, but maybe it could help you.

You should move `handleClick` function to `TodoList.tsx` and use [`mutate`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation) to update client cache (`data`)

```
const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/v1/todos-all', fetcher);

...

const handleClick = (todo, value) => {
  axios.put(`/api/v1/todo/${todo._id}`, { completed: !value}).then(() => {
    todo.completed = value;
    mutate([...todos]);
  });
};

return
  ...
    {
      data.todos.map((todo: any) =>
        todo.completed ? (
          <Todo key={todo._id} todo={todo} onClick={handleClick} />
        ) : null
      );
    }
```

Todo.tsx

```
...
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value={todo.checked}
  onChange={(e) => onClick(todo, e.target.checked)}
/>
```

Comment: I thought on that solution, but what if I do not want to complete the task when clicking any part of the todo? I mean, in a future I want to have more buttons like edit or delete, If I do that I won't be able to make more buttons

Comment: The code above only fire onClick event when you check/uncheck a checkbox. If you want to add another button or something to <Todo /> component, you just need to add another event such as onEdit, onDelete on that button and listen on it at parent component. It will work as you want.

Comment: Hmmm in this solution what does `mutate=([...todos])` refers to, I don't have any variable called todos?